# Issue with validating a user-selected amount of appended input forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to validate a set of inputs that are being appended based on a pre-selected value.

Psudo-code version:
   Select from a list of options with values set from 0-10

On change Javascript appends 0-10 input forms with incrementing values of w, starting from 0 (so the names are dinnerform0, dinnerform1, dinnerform2, etc for all that exist).

```
$('#dinnerQty').change(function(){
      dinnerQty = $('#dinnerQty').val() ;
      if(dinnerQty > 0){
          $('#dinnerForm').empty();
          $('#dinnerFormCont').show();
          for (w = 0; w <= (dinnerQty-1); w++) {
               $('#dinnerForm').append('<div class="dinnerformcloneinput"> <input type="text" class="foodform" name="dinnerFirstName' + w +'" placeholder="First Name" /> <input type="text" class="foodform" name="dinnerLastName'+ w +'" placeholder="Last Name" /> </div>')
          }
      } else {
              $('#dinnerFormCont').hide();
              $('#dinnerForm').empty();
      }
});
```

For Validation I've been trying to do it based on each input like this but haven't been able to get it to work.

```
   $('input .foodform').each(function() {
          if ($("input").val() == ""){
    alert("You must enter a First and Last Name for each Dinner Guest");
    return false;
    }
   }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: show your html and be clear in your question so that we can answer. A jsfiddle would be good though

Comment: my bad I'll make sure to do that in the future, I thought I was clear I needed help with the validation of the appended inputs but I'll be clearer in the future. I don't think the html would matter here much though, considering the necessary html is what's being appended inside of a div and is above in the javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this like,

```
$('input.foodform').each(function() {
// -----^ remove space from here if you input has foodform class
   if (this.value == ""){ // use this.value or $(this).val()
      alert("You must enter a First and Last Name for each Dinner Guest");
      return false;
   }
});
```